# Why is this generating an Index Out of Bounds error?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I have tried to figure out why the loop in createArithmeticSeq is going out of bounds, but can't figure it out. The loop should be stopping when i=listSize-1, since it's (i=0;i  < listSize; i++). Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MagicSquare 
{
static int row, col, n, rows, columns, listSize;
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
```

This is where the issue is occurring:

```
public static void createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)
    {   
    //prompt user for array size
    System.out.println("Enter size of array (in form nxn), n:");
    n = console.nextInt();
    rows = n;
    columns = n;
    listSize= (n*n);
    int first; 
    int diff;
    //prompt user for first and diff
    System.out.println("Enter first and diff : ");
    first = console.nextInt();
    diff  = console.nextInt();
    //process to create list of n*n elements 
    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i]=first+i*diff;
    }
}
```

And here is the rest of the code:

```
public static void matricize (int [] list, int [][] matrix)
{
    int i = 0;
//loop through each row
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
    //loop through each column
        for (col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        {
        //populate matrix with values from list
        matrix[row][col] = list[i++];
        }
     }
}
public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
{

    for (row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("%2d" + " ", matrix[row][col]);

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}

public static void reverseDiagonal(int [] [] matrix)
{ 
    int temp;
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length / 2; row++)
    {
        temp = matrix[row][row];
        matrix[row][row] = 
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row] [matrix.length - 1 - row];
        matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][matrix.length - 1 - row] = temp;
    }
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length / 2; row++)
    {
        temp = matrix[row][matrix.length - 1 - row];
        matrix[row][matrix.length - 1 - row] = 
            matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][row];
        matrix[matrix.length - 1 - row][row] = temp;
    }
}

public static void magicCheck(int [] list, int [] [] matrix)
{
    int sum=0, sumRow=0, sumCol=0, sumDiag1=0, sumDiag2=0, magicNumber=0;

    for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        sum += list[i]; 
        magicNumber = sum /= 4;

    for(row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
            //sum each row, then compare to magicNumber
        for(col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        sumRow = sumRow + matrix[row][col];
        while (sumRow == magicNumber)
        {
            for(col=0; col<matrix.length; col++)
            {
                for(row=0; row<matrix[col].length; row++)
                {
                sumCol = sumCol + matrix[row][col];
                    while (sumCol == magicNumber)
                    {
                    sumDiag1 = matrix[0][0]+matrix[1][1]+matrix[2][2]+matrix[3][3];
                        while (sumDiag1 == magicNumber)
                        {
                        sumDiag2 = matrix[3][0]+matrix[2][1]+matrix[1][2]
                        +matrix[0][3];
                            while(sumDiag2 == magicNumber)
                            System.out.println("It is a magic square.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
            System.out.println("It is not a magic square.");

}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int [] list = new int [listSize];
    createArithmeticSeq (list);
    int [] [] matrix = new int [rows] [columns];
    matricize(list, matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.print("\n");
    reverseDiagonal(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    magicCheck(list, matrix);   
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `listsize` as `static`, it gets the default value of `0`. And then you call `createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)`, you are basically passing a list with space for 0 elements. If you change the value of `listsize` after you have created `int [] list = new int [listSize];`, the size of list doesn't change. Hence, you have to create the array after you know what size it would be.

To do that, modify your main method as

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter size of array (in form nxn), n:");
    n = console.nextInt();
    rows = n;
    columns = n;
    listSize= (n*n);    
    int [] list = new int [listSize];
    createArithmeticSeq (list);
    int [] [] matrix = new int [rows] [columns];
    matricize(list, matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.print("\n");
    reverseDiagonal(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    magicCheck(list, matrix);   
}
```

And your createArithmeticSeq method as

```
public static void createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)
{   
    int first; 
    int diff;
    //prompt user for first and diff
    System.out.println("Enter first and diff : ");
    first = console.nextInt();
    diff  = console.nextInt();
    //process to create list of n*n elements 
    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i]=first+i*diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed a key-logger on by PC dude? ;) What a synchro!

Comment: @Pragmateek I answered it by bits, first the theory, and then the code.

Comment: The same way: first ninja rush with short answer then enrich to be perfect :) you've got my +1 of course

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. That makes perfect sense, I just overlooked it.

Answer (score 4):

When you are creating list array in `main` you are using `listSize`. Since you don't initialice it, its value is 0.

In `createArithmeticSeq` method you change it's size to `n*n`, but this doesn't efect the size of the array witch still is 0.

Answer (score 2):

In your main you create the list array using the uninitialized "*listSize*" value which will be 0.
So you should change your code to first read the list size then creating the array:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //prompt user for array size
    System.out.println("Enter size of array (in form nxn), n:");
    n = console.nextInt();
    rows = n;
    columns = n;
    listSize= (n*n);

    int [] list = new int [listSize];
    createArithmeticSeq (list);
    int [] [] matrix = new int [rows] [columns];
    matricize(list, matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    System.out.print("\n");
    reverseDiagonal(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    magicCheck(list, matrix);   
}
```

And your function becomes:

```
public static void createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)
{   
    int first; 
    int diff;
    //prompt user for first and diff
    System.out.println("Enter first and diff : ");
    first = console.nextInt();
    diff  = console.nextInt();
    //process to create list of n*n elements 
    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i]=first+i*diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have asked you the same question ;)

Comment: LOL, thats why I deleted mine ;)